# Converting numbers to particular string format in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, string-formatting

I need to run a task which can be done with a loop, but I imagine that there is a more efficient and pretty way to do this. I have a `DataFrame` which has an integer column, which I would like to transform to a 4-digit string representation. That is, 3 should be converted to '0003', 234 should be converted to '0234'. I am looking for a vector operation that will do this to all entries in the column at once, quickly with simple code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use [Series.str.zfill()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) method:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)
```

Demo:

```
In [29]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[3,234]})

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
   a    b
0  1    3
1  2  234

In [31]: df['b'] = df['b'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)

In [32]: df
Out[32]:
   a     b
0  1  0003
1  2  0234
```

Comment: First time i have seen this one, nice @MaxU +1

Comment: Nice, but the transformation is applied AFTER the int column is converted to string. Technically, does not answer the quesstion.

Comment: @jpmartineau, OP asked: "which I would like to transform to a 4-digit __string representation__" - i think it answers exactly that. ;)

Answer (score 8):

You can also do this using the [Series.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) method and an f-string wrapped in a lambda function:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd


In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[3,234]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   a    b
0  1    3
1  2  234

In [4]: df['b'] = df['b'].apply(lambda x: f"{x:04d}")

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   a     b
0  1  0003
1  2  0234
```

In the f-string, the [part after the colon](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) says "zero-pad the field with four characters and make it a signed base-10 integer".

Comment: This reply better answers to the title (but not to the description) of the question

Comment: How does it not fit the description? It is "a vector operation that will do this to all entries in the column at once, quickly with simple code".

Comment: The description only asks for zero padding so str.zfill seemed more appropriate. However, from a quick timeit, it seems apply is twice faster for a 100000 vector.

Comment: From the linked format specification for f-strings: "When no explicit alignment is given, preceding the width field by a zero ('0') character **enables sign-aware zero-padding** for numeric types. This is equivalent to a fill character of '0' with an alignment type of '='." (emphasis mine).