# Replacing numeric value with a different numeric value

Tags: python, pandas

I imported a CSV file in Python. One of the fields is numeric with 11 digits. The first 2 digits all start with 27. How can i replace the 27 with a 0?

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and add some more details. How does your data look like, can you make a [mre]? What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting numbers to particular string format in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41749681/converting-numbers-to-particular-string-format-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: to remove 27..., e.g. like `(pd.Series([27000000001])-27000000000).astype(str).str.zfill(11)`?

Answer (score 0):

Just try following code:
df['column_name']=df['column_name'].replace([original_value], new_value)
if you want to replace more than one values:
df['column_name']=df['column_name'].replace([v1, v2, v3], [a, b, c])

Answer (score 0):

Let say your column looks like this

```
    column_name
0   273525235
1   2724112414124
2   34214124124
```

---

1. `astype('string')` is converting that numeric column to `string` first
2. Using `str.replace('27', '00')` replace `27` with `00` and then
3. `astype('int64')` will convert that string column to numeric again.

   ```
   data['column_name'] = data['column_name'].astype('string').str.replace('27', '00').astype('int64')
   ```

---

### Output

```
    column_name
0   3525235
1   24112414124
2   34214124124
```